# Как написать многоуровневое меню на Go для телеграмм бота

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, golang

Возможно есть бест практисы по этому, но я ничего не нашёл и весь код у меня состоит примерно из такого:

```
switch callbackQuery.Data {
    case CommandUserStart:
    case ...:
и т.д.
```

И как условно сделать начало "Опроса", в котором вначале будут спрашивать ФИО, вуз(инлайн кнопки) и номер группы, после этого можно будет либо редактировать, либо начинать опросник. И как сделать продвижение по нему

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ использовать пакет:
https://github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api
И дополнение к нему, которой в python-telegram-bot называется ConversationHandler'ы. Они уже реализованы как дополнение к пакету:
https://github.com/and3rson/telemux?tab=readme-ov-file

Выглядеть будет примерно так:

```
mux := tm.NewMux().
    AddHandler(tm.NewCommandHandler(
        "start",
        func(u *tm.Update) {
            bot.Send(tgbotapi.NewMessage(u.Message.Chat.ID, "Hello! Say something. :)"))
        },
    )).
    AddHandler(tm.NewHandler(
        tm.Any(),
        func(u *tm.Update) {
            bot.Send(tgbotapi.NewMessage(u.Message.Chat.ID, "You said: "+u.Message.Text))
        },
    ))
```

Либо можно написать свою поддержку подобных хендлеров.

- Соотносишь команду с хендлером
- Хендлеры заносишь в мапу по ключу команды
- При получении команды от пользователя проверяешь ее наличие в мапе и вызываешь метод хендлера, в который можешь передать ответ и обработать как тебе нужно